# Reduntant files in GitHub

Tags: github, github-pages, redundancy

I was performing commits with minor changes in my code and did a lot of them. At the end when I see my github account couple of files are redundant with same name but with a tilde character at the end.

Example : There are 2 files index.html and index.html~

If I pull the latest version to my local repository to remove them, I don't see the files with (~) at the end. I however did some edits directly on the github web portal. Is it because of that?

I didn't create multiple branches as well, but was working on the master branch.

I would like to know why there are redundant files and how to get rid of them from my github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably did

```
git add .
```

You may not have '.gitignore' file too.

The ~ files are created by your text editor when you are editing your file.

Just create a .gitignore file and add this to the file

```
~
```

Then commit the gitignore file too.
In the future, avoid using

```
git add .
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried adding the .gitignore but and pushing the files again, but it didn't work. It gave me a message "Already uptodate". I found the reason was that  the files were in my local repository, but were hidden in the file explorer. So I had to use git rm <filenames> for all the files with ~ and then commit. Probably for a new repository its better to do it as you suggested - adding .gitignore initially when I do the first commit. It will work.